# Boost bootstrap.bat crashes in my DOS cmd line

Tags: c++, windows, boost, boost-signals2

I had copied the boost directory of a colleague. It was running fine out of the box as is.

But now I have a problem, I have some new code using boost.signals that compiles well but **doesn't link** since I don't have the `libboost_signals-vc100-mt-gd-1_48.lib` file in my bin directory. (I already have thread, regex and some other library binaries, but not the signals one).

So I have started looking at the [Boost Install procedure](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#or-simplified-build-from-source) so as to build Boost.Signals2

And whether I want to install Boost.Build or build Boost.Signals2, the batch script **bootstraps.bat** makes my MS-DOS command window crash without error message. It takes about 10 seconds to do so after writing "Bootstrapping the build engine" or "Bootstraping Boost.Build engine".

```
rem install Boost.Build
cd "Program Files\boost_1_48_0\boost_1_48_0"
cd tools\build\v2\.
bootstrap.bat
b2 install --prefix="C:\Boost.Build"
```

or

```
rem build signals2
cd "Program Files\boost_1_48_0\boost_1_48_0"
bootstrap
./b2 signals2 variant=debug link=static threading=multi address-model=64
```

I don't know where to start investigating ? Any idea ? Have I forgotten something obvious ?

Comment: Boost.Signals2 is header-only, you can't build it separately. Probably you mean the older Boost.Signals?

Comment: this is my error message when linking: LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_signals-vc100-mt-gd-1_48.lib'

Comment: Do you mean that I wrote code that needs signals v1 binaries, whereas I only wanted to use signals v2. I'm gonna check that.

Comment: but **anyway**, if I wanted to install something else (for example Boost.Python) I would love to have bootstrap.bat not to crash :-)

Comment: you copied the directory from another machine; perhaps rebuilding everything with 'b2 -a' will help. worst case download a fresh copy.

Comment: @Stephane Rolland First of all, your code uses Signals, not Signals2, so check that out. As for bootsrap crash - you don't provide any relevant details (how does it "crash"? doesn't it work without explicit invocation of bootstrap?). Besides, the syntax of b2 line seems to be incorrect, it should be --with-signals.

Comment: @JohnDibling  yes it is indeed 1.48. My colleagues said that it is the lattest version with which we could use boost.log (that is not part of the boost package yet).

Comment: @AnonymousCoward i'm gonna try b2 -a

Comment: @IgorR. Well I really don't have any additionnal information as I wrote it. launching bootstrap.bat crashes the cmd-line without any error messages. I haven't tried without calling bootstrap.bat since I'm asked to call it in "Boost Get Started". But I'm gonna try without. Why should I use the flag "--with-signals" ? it is not documented here http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/overview/invocation.html

Comment: @Stephane Rolland as for the syntax - sorry, I wasn't updated, with b2 your syntax seems to be ok.

Comment: @IgorR. Many thanx! At some places I was using signal v1 and at other places signal v2. I put everything in order and now it links ok with only signal v2. I will come back later to check this bootstrap story.